# dbset object of one model in controller of different model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unhandled-exception, dbset

New to MVC framework. I am getting below error when i am trying to pass dbset object of one model in controller of different model.

below is the code

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    
    return View(db.designations.ToList());
}
```

Create action is of employee model where as db.designation.tolist() belongs to designation model.

Comment: You need to return a model in your view or leave it empty

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.